# Installing pytorch with conda

Tags: python, pytorch

I've just been trying to dabble in AI in the past few weeks, I've tried installing pytorch with conda and it all seems to work but then I get the error:

`ImportError: /home/lp35791/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cuda.so: cannot read file data`

I've been trawling through the web but can't seem to find the answer to this error. I've uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda and when I made a new environment and installed numpy along with pytorch, numpy imported successfully but pytorch did not. I'm just wondering what the problem is. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have installed PyTorch in your base environment, you therefore cannot use it from your other "pytorch" env.

Either:

directly create a new environment (let's call it pytorch_env) with PyTorch: `conda create -n pytorch_env -c pytorch pytorch torchvision`

switch to the pytorch environment you have already created with: `source activate pytorch_env` and then install PyTorch in it: `conda install -c pytorch pytorch torchvision`

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you need to reinstall it-
Go to terminal type

`pip uninstall pytorch`

then again type

`pip install pytorch`

if you are unable to install you will get solution there itself.

Comment: The user used conda to install pytorch, not pip.